# Attempt to read property "username" on bool

Tags: laravel, relationship, one-to-many, eager-loading

I am trying to use "Eager loading relationship" in Laravel.

I use `one-to-many` relationship, I am trying to access the information I want in the `.blade.php` file with `@foreach` but with the error `Attempt to read property "username" on bool` I'm facing

This is my user model `User.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function nfts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Nft::class);
    }

}
```

This is my Nft model `Nft.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nft extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,SoftDeletes;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'nfts';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is my controller `NftController`

```
public function getNft(int $id):view
    {
        $nft = Nft::with('user')->find($id);
        return view('nfts.singleNft', ['nft'=>$nft]);
    }
```

and this is my `userinfo.blade.php` page

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($nft->user as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><span class="badge bg-primary">{{$user->username}}</span></td>
            .
            .
            .
```

What is the problem?

Comment: $nft->user is not a collection thats why you can't iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over a *collection* of items.
Your `nft` is a *single* model, not a collection.

Drop the `foreach`

```php
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><span class="badge bg-primary">{{$nft->user->username}}</span></td>
            .
            .
            .
```